# extract data from json file into excel

Tags: python, json, excel, pandas

I have a json file and the outut is shown below:

```
{
    "IdentityDocuments": [
        {
            "DocumentIndex": 1,
            "IdentityDocumentFields": [
                {
                    "Type": {
                        "Text": "FIRST_NAME"
                    },
                    "ValueDetection": {
                        "Text": "CLAUS",
                        "Confidence": 98.9039535522461
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Type": {
                        "Text": "LAST_NAME"
                    },
                    "ValueDetection": {
                        "Text": "SANTA",
                        "Confidence": 98.62335968017578
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Type": {
                        "Text": "MIDDLE_NAME"
                    },
                    "ValueDetection": {
                        "Text": "NOVA",
                        "Confidence": 99.01791381835938
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Type": {
                        "Text": "SUFFIX"
                    },
                    "ValueDetection": {
                        "Text": "",
                        "Confidence": 99.52413940429688
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Type": {
                        "Text": "CITY_IN_ADDRESS"
                    },
                    "ValueDetection": {
                        "Text": "",
                        "Confidence": 99.63380432128906
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Type": {
                        "Text": "ZIP_CODE_IN_ADDRESS"
                    },
                    "ValueDetection": {
                        "Text": "",
                        "Confidence": 99.66967010498047
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Type": {
                        "Text": "STATE_IN_ADDRESS"
                    },
                    "ValueDetection": {
                        "Text": "",
                        "Confidence": 99.638427734375
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Type": {
                        "Text": "STATE_NAME"
                    },
                    "ValueDetection": {
                        "Text": "",
                        "Confidence": 98.48577117919922
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Type": {
                        "Text": "DOCUMENT_NUMBER"
                    },
                    "ValueDetection": {
                        "Text": "GC000000",
                        "Confidence": 94.45845031738281
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Type": {
                        "Text": "EXPIRATION_DATE"
                    },
                    "ValueDetection": {
                        "Text": "",
                        "Confidence": 23.559080123901367
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Type": {
                        "Text": "DATE_OF_BIRTH"
                    },
                    "ValueDetection": {
                        "Text": "25 DEC IDEC",
                        "Confidence": 70.85164642333984
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Type": {
                        "Text": "DATE_OF_ISSUE"
                    },
                    "ValueDetection": {
                        "Text": "",
                        "Confidence": 42.78477478027344
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Type": {
                        "Text": "ID_TYPE"
                    },
                    "ValueDetection": {
                        "Text": "PASSPORT",
                        "Confidence": 99.32125091552734
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Type": {
                        "Text": "ENDORSEMENTS"
                    },
                    "ValueDetection": {
                        "Text": "",
                        "Confidence": 99.26473999023438
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Type": {
                        "Text": "VETERAN"
                    },
                    "ValueDetection": {
                        "Text": "",
                        "Confidence": 99.59288024902344
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Type": {
                        "Text": "RESTRICTIONS"
                    },
                    "ValueDetection": {
                        "Text": "",
                        "Confidence": 99.5494613647461
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Type": {
                        "Text": "CLASS"
                    },
                    "ValueDetection": {
                        "Text": "",
                        "Confidence": 99.61245727539062
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Type": {
                        "Text": "ADDRESS"
                    },
                    "ValueDetection": {
                        "Text": "",
                        "Confidence": 99.61029052734375
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Type": {
                        "Text": "COUNTY"
                    },
                    "ValueDetection": {
                        "Text": "",
                        "Confidence": 99.6097412109375
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Type": {
                        "Text": "PLACE_OF_BIRTH"
                    },
                    "ValueDetection": {
                        "Text": "",
                        "Confidence": 14.484281539916992
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
```

```
Wanted to populate values in excel like

| Type              | Text           |Confidence          
| --------          | -------------- |--------------
| PLACE_OF_BIRTH    | ""             |14.484281539916992
| DATE_OF_BIRTH     | ""
| --------          | -------------- |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `pd.json_normalize` then export dataframe to excel

```py
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('data.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())

df = pd.json_normalize(data['IdentityDocuments'], record_path='IdentityDocumentFields')
df = df.rename(columns={'Type.Text': 'Type', 'ValueDetection.Text': 'Text', 'ValueDetection.Confidence': 'Confidence'})
df.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

```
print(df)

                   Type         Text  Confidence
0            FIRST_NAME        CLAUS   98.903954
1             LAST_NAME        SANTA   98.623360
2           MIDDLE_NAME         NOVA   99.017914
3                SUFFIX                99.524139
4       CITY_IN_ADDRESS                99.633804
5   ZIP_CODE_IN_ADDRESS                99.669670
6      STATE_IN_ADDRESS                99.638428
7            STATE_NAME                98.485771
8       DOCUMENT_NUMBER     GC000000   94.458450
9       EXPIRATION_DATE                23.559080
10        DATE_OF_BIRTH  25 DEC IDEC   70.851646
11        DATE_OF_ISSUE                42.784775
12              ID_TYPE     PASSPORT   99.321251
13         ENDORSEMENTS                99.264740
14              VETERAN                99.592880
15         RESTRICTIONS                99.549461
16                CLASS                99.612457
17              ADDRESS                99.610291
18               COUNTY                99.609741
19       PLACE_OF_BIRTH                14.484282
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `json` with `loads` and `json_normalize` methods

```
import pandas as pd
import json

with open('data.json', 'r') as json_file:
    json_value = json_file.read().replace('\n', '')
    data = json.loads(json_value)
    df = pd.json_normalize(data['IdentityDocuments'][0]['IdentityDocumentFields'])
    df.to_excel('excel_from_json.xlsx')
```

**Sample output from the generated excel:**
[image]